# Matlab edit RGB values

Tags: matlab

I have buttons that need to increase\decrease an colour level for RGB. Tried doing something like this

```
im3 = im3(:,:,1) + 2;
```

but it creates some weird image glitch. any ideas? 
i'm not a pro so i'm probably going about this all wrong but any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Shai: know that the [homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and should not be added to questions

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that you should consider:

1. `im3 = im3(:,:,1) + 2;` assigns the new value to `img3` variable and makes it a 2D matrix. You should do `im3(:,:,1) = im3(:,:,1) + 2;`. to increase all the values by 2 in third channel.
2. Addition might result in larger values than the permitted values for an image. You may consider using [`imadd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadd.html).
3. Image variables are usually of type `double` or type `uint8`. If the values are `double`, the values are real and in between 0 and 1. If the values are `unit8`, the values are integers in between 0 and 255. Adding by 2 is reasonable if the type is `uint8`, but it is not when the type is `double`. You should add by 2/255 if so. You can use `im2double` or `im2uint8` for type conversions with proper scaling. Be aware of the class of the `img` variable by running `class(img)`.

Comment: Thankyou, it all makes sense now & its only a simple college assignment so i'll just use the original matrix.